# How to unlock my new iPad by just sliding to the right?

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, authorization, touch-id

On my iPad mini, when the screen is locked, I unlock it by just sliding to the right. This is very nice.

I want to be able to do the same on my all new iPad Air 2.

It seems that the only way to do that is to turn off Touch ID (the fingerprint reading). I don't want to turn off Touch ID.

**How can I be able to unlock my new iPad by just sliding to the right? Without turning off Touch ID.**

On the new iPad, I have iOS 8.2.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of Touch ID

Comment: @ColeJohnson Not at all. My iPad is only ever in my home. If an adversary was in my home and wanted to access my iPad, I have bigger problems. Nonetheless, it's nice to have it for banking apps, 1Password, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**This isn't possible.** Enabling Touch ID enables a passcode, which must be entered on the lock screen. If you do not wish to have a passcode, then you must disable Touch ID too. Also, because you have Touch ID enabled, you are unable to adjust the Require Passcode time in Settings → Touch ID & Passcode → Require Passcode.

The only workaround is to go to Settings → Touch ID & Passcode, disable iPhone Unlock, then set Require Passcode to After 1 hour. This means that you won't be prompted for a passcode if you use your device less than an hour after you last used it.

Video demonstration of workaround: [Touch ID Require Passcode Timer](https://georgegarside.com/o/se/touchid/)

Comment: This is definitely a frustrating feature. I don't care to have a password on my lock screen but would prefer to use Touch ID to purchase App Store items without a password.

Comment: Even the workaround is not possible on my iPad.

Comment: @Nicolas I've added a video of how to do the workaround to my answer.

Comment: The video is nice, but aren't you leaving out the rather important detail that in order to set it to "1 hour", you just have the "iPhone Unlock" toggled OFF, which means you **give up** the security of the Touch ID sensor? In fact, after one hour elapses, you must manually enter your passcode. I would say something like "This does not address the Question" but then your first paragraph in your answer already describes everything properly. So I'm just confused. That being said, your video does address @RyanMartin's comment.

Comment: Thank you, but the settings you describe are not possible on my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You *could theoretically* jailbreak and install [Mesalation](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/02/03/mesalation/).

I may have already done this on my iPhone 6+. It may be working quite well.

Comment: Minus infinity to Apple for making you have to 'suggest' a solution that seems like it would **certainly suffice the OP's requirements**.

Comment: This is useful, but the jailbreak tweak is completely superfluous…? All you need to do is disable the iPhone Unlock option of Touch ID and then the full list of Require Passcode options are available.

Comment: @grgarside OP doesn't want to turn off Touch ID, but really the only response that is truly necessary is the comment on the question.

Comment: I don't do jailbreak.

Comment: @grgarside, Steven Lu — I don't understand. Is there a solution without jailbreak?

Comment: I think @grgarside might just be actually wrong (on account of Nicolas stating "without turning off Touch ID"). Nicolas, No, there is no solution without JB, if you turn on Touch ID, then you are locked into the Require Passcode Immediately mode.

Comment: @StevenLu I've added a video of how to do the workaround to my answer.

Comment: @grgarside - There is no "iPhone Unlock" option on my iPad. I rather like that.